# How to add facebook og:meta tags in LAYOUT.xml in magento?

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I want to insert Facebook og:meta tags to use for facebook sharer ,in a head of a particular page and this page is not a CMS page.I am thinking of adding these tags through that extension  layout file.
I know normal titles and description are added like this ->

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle"><title>My Module Page</title></action>   
 </reference>
```

Does magento provides something like this for Facbook og:meta tags?If not ,what is/are  the other method to put og:meta tags in the head of a page so that it work with facebook sharer.

Comment: what about set it programatically on the fly?Do you have any source for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento doesn't include an action to include these meta tags. Instead, you could create a template file (/app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/page/html/facebookmeta.phtml) with your meta tags in it.

Then, add the following to your `head` reference:

```
<block type="core/template" name="facebookmeta" template="page/html/facebookmeta.phtml" />
```

Clear your caches and you should see your block being included into the head for that particular page. It's not a particularly extendable solution, if you want to pass options to this template you should really create a new block, which requires creating a new module etc.

However, in your template file you can use PHP, so you should be able to get various variables you need, for example:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName() ?>"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but also you need add '$this->getChildHtml('facebookmeta');' to the head.phtml

Comment: How to add on the fly meta for facebook share on any page?

Answer (score 13):

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="blockname">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: I don't think this applies here, because you can't specify the image src dynamically.